# Javascript One Page Fixed Header Responsive Slideup and Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I figured out how to make it so the header disappears upon click when viewing within a mobile version but it also disappears when you're not in mobile version. How do I make it so if it's not in mobile version, it will not disappear upon click?

HTML

```
    <header>
    <div class="head_container">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><h1>Hello</h1></a>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="top_menu">Hello</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#homepage">HomePage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

CSS for Desktop

```
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: right;
    font: 14px Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

nav li a {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin: 0 .15em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

nav a {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a#top_menu {
    display: none;
} 

nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    color: #8148c1;
}
```

CSS For Mobile

```
nav {
    float: none;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
}

nav li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 0;
}

nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav a#top_menu {
    display: block;
    background-position: 20px 17px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;   
}

nav a#top_menu:after {
    content:"";
    background: url('../images/mini.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    menu = $("nav ul");
    $(top_menu).click(function () {
        if ($('nav ul').is(':visible')) {
            menu.slideUp()
        } else {
            menu.slideDown()
        }
    });

    $('nav li a').click(function () {
        menu.slideUp()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the viewport width in your javascript & only make the menu slide up & down if its a mobile viewport.

**This should work -**

```
$(function () {
    menu = $("nav ul");

    var preferredMobileViewPortWidth = "480"; /* you can keep this as your mobile media query width */
    var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
    var isMobile = false;

    if(viewPortWidth <= preferredMobileViewPortWidth) {
      isMobile = true;
    }
    $(top_menu).click(function () {
        if(isMobile) {
          if ($('nav ul').is(':visible')) {
              menu.slideUp()
          } else {
              menu.slideDown()
          }
        }
    });

    $('nav li a').click(function () {
        if(isMobile) {
         menu.slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't even slide down anymore.

Comment: what is the viewport width of your mobile device. as in what are you using as max width in your media queries for phone css?

Comment: The mobile version shows up with a max-width of 950px.

Comment: 950? are you sure thats almost a desktop viewport? well in that case at least test the code by change the viewport value to 950 in my code. But again, there's something else wrong because mobile viewport should not be 950px.

Comment: Works when I test it on a phone. But is there a way to test it on a browser? Doesn't work when I shrink my browser to try to test it out.

Comment: when you resize window, it has already calculated the viewport for the desktop, so won't work. So once you resize you can refresh again in that resized mode & test. Otherwise you can add a window resize event & re call this script so it gets the current viewport width on window resize. Hope I am clear

Comment: Oooo okay. Thank you for the help Nitish!

Comment: you may accept & upvote the answer if it worked for you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for width of your viewport:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     viewPort = (window).width();
     menu = $("nav ul");
      if( viewPort < 500) {

        $(top_menu).click(function () {
            if ($('nav ul').is(':visible')) {
                menu.slideUp()
            } else {
                menu.slideDown()
            }
        });

        $('nav li a').click(function () {
            menu.slideUp()
        });
      }
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand the coding you just showed but it no longer slides down the moment I just put "viewport = (window).width();". Do you know why that is?

Comment: Because JQuery executes the function when the page loads. If you put 

$( window ).resize(function() {
  viewPort = $(window).width();
});

 It will readjust the width each time you resize the window. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Those scripts](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) can help you if you want to detect mobile devices and add a test on your Javascript.

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#touch) can do it pretty well too.